# No me guarda los archivos en jpg PHP

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un sistema que me gestione archivos en PNG, JGP Y PDF, el sistema ya esta funcional, pero cuando intento subir un archivo JPG no funciona, con PNG si funciona igual que con PDF, pero no pasa nada al subir un archivo JPG, este es mi codigo.

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $title = $con->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['title']));
    $description = $con->real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['description']));

$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$new_name_file = null;

if ($file_name != '' || $file_name != null) {
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    list($type, $extension) = explode('/', $file_type);
    if ($extension == 'pdf' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'jpg') {
        $dir = 'files/';
        if (!file_exists($dir)) {
            mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
        }
        $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        //$new_name_file = 'files/' . date('Ymdhis') . '.' . $extension;
        $new_name_file = $dir . file_name($file_name) . '.' . $extension;
        if (copy($file_tmp_name, $new_name_file)) {
            
        }
    }
}

$ins = $con->query("INSERT INTO files(title,description,url) VALUES ('$title','$description','$new_name_file')");

if ($ins) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrégale tambien `jpeg` a la lista de extensiones, pues tambien es probable que a veces devuelva `image/jpeg`:

Cambia esto:

```
if ($extension == 'pdf' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'jpg') {
```

por esto:

```
if ($extension == 'pdf' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg') {
```

Comment: Broo Muchas Gracias, ese era el problema, ya lo resolvi gracias a eso!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)