# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se elimine la ruta y la imagen cuando actualizo solo datos con php?

Tags: php

Si alguien con experiencia me pudiera dar una mano en orientarme en que estoy mal.

¿Qué no hace la validación para que no me modifique la ruta y no elimine la foto si hay una existente, a menos que seleccione una?

Dejo mi código para que le de un vistazo , gracias!!

```
$consulta2 = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT foto FROM alm WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
$consulta2->execute();
$resultado2 = $consulta2->get_result();
$row = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();

if(isset($row['foto'])){
    if(file_exists('../'.$row['foto'])){
        unlink('../'.$row['foto']);
    }
}
$extension = '';
$ruta ='images/alumnos';
$archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['tmp_name'];
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['name'];
$info = pathinfo($nombre_archivo);

if ($archivo != ''){

    $extension=$info['extension'];
    if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension== "JPG" || $extension== "PNG" || $extension =="png" ){

        move_uploaded_file($archivo,'../images/alumnos/'.$nombre_archivo);
        $ruta = $ruta."/".$nombre_archivo;

    }else{
        header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=el formato no es valido&c=us&p=in&t=error');
        exit;
    }
    $consulta1= $mysqli->prepare ("UPDATE alm SET foto = '$ruta' WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
    $resultado1 = $consulta1->get_result();
    $consulta1->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final creo haber entendido que no quieres que se borre la imagen a menos que se suba alguna nueva.

Por lo tanto tu código deberia quedar así:

```
$consulta2 = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT foto FROM alm WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
$consulta2->execute();
$resultado2 = $consulta2->get_result();
$row = $resultado2->fetch_assoc();

$extension = '';
$ruta ='images/alumnos';
$archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['tmp_name'];
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['txtfoto']['name'];
$info = pathinfo($nombre_archivo);

if ($archivo != ''){

    $extension=$info['extension'];
    if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension== "JPG" || $extension== "PNG" || $extension =="png" ){

        if(isset($row['foto'])){
            if(file_exists('../'.$row['foto'])){
                unlink('../'.$row['foto']);
            }
        }

        move_uploaded_file($archivo,'../images/alumnos/'.$nombre_archivo);
        $ruta = $ruta."/".$nombre_archivo;

    }else{
        header('location:../extend/alerta.php?msj=el formato no es valido&c=us&p=in&t=error');
        exit;
    }
    $consulta1= $mysqli->prepare ("UPDATE alm SET foto = '$ruta' WHERE matricula = '$matricula' ");
    $resultado1 = $consulta1->get_result();
    $consulta1->execute();
}
```

Prueba y nos cuentas a ver si ahora te va bien.

Básicamente he condicionado la eliminación de la imagen actual **sólo** si hay un archivo de subida y además tiene la extensión válida. ¿Era eso lo que querias?

Es decir, he movido este trozo de código dentro de los dos condicionales `if` para evitar eliminar nada antes de verificar que se sube algo y además con la extensión correcta:

```
    if(isset($row['foto'])){
        if(file_exists('../'.$row['foto'])){
            unlink('../'.$row['foto']);
        }
    }
```

Comment: En efecto colega no me explique bien una disculpa, mi pregunta era que estaba haciendo mal en mi código que no realizaba la acción de que no se borre la imagen a menos que se suba alguna nueva, ya que modificaba algún otro dato en el formulario y me quitaba la imagen.

Comment: Entonces he contestado bien :-)  Me alegro de que ahora te funcione. En cuanto a las extensiones, te recomiendo tambien agregar .jpeg/.JPEG pues tambien podrias encontrarte con ese caso, que ademas, si filtraras por el filetype de la imagen, tiene su propio MIME, como puedes ver en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/506454/no-me-guarda-los-archivos-en-jpg-php/506458#506458).

Comment: Oohh buena sugerencia la voy a revisar amigo, una consulta más jejeje voy a realizar otra pregunta referente a este tema, tengo una cuestión si se cambia la imagen del usuario como lo hace el código, como puedo evitar que si en la bd si tengo almacenada una ruta de una imagen predeterminada en el campo foto, no me elimine en especifico esa foto cuando se cambia la ruta, ya que me afectaría a los demás que tengan la imagen predeterminada.

Comment: Vaya, perdona, no se porque no me habia llegado este comentario antes, no he recibido ningun aviso de el. Acabo de ver tu pregunta nueva y la respuesta que te ha dado triby es correcta, solo que debes cambiar el nombre de la imagen por defecto que ha puesto por la que es realmente tu predeterminada. Aun así tambien revisaria esa parte del código y permitiria no tener ninguna imagen guardada, y en ese caso poner la predeterminada cuando muestras los perfiles (pero sin codigo no puedo ayudarte alli, quizas en una nueva pregunta si realmente te interesa asi)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda colega, si en mi otra pregunta ya coloque el código completo para ver en que puedo estar mal.